# Upgrading Windows 8 Consumer Preview to Release Preview

Tags: windows-8, upgrade, operating-systems

I currently have my main hard drive split into two partitions. One being Windows 7 with about 600 GB of memory, the other Windows 8 Consumer Preview with about 50 GB. As you can guess it is set up for a dual boot.

Today while looking up how to get the C# Facebook SDK for Metro apps I learned about the Release Preview being released. I was wondering: How do I go about getting rid of Windows 8 Consumer Preview and replacing it with the Release Preview?

I know i can't just wipe it off my second partition because the dual boot uses Windows 8 to choose the operating system to boot.

Comment: Did you try just installing it?  At least in my VM it offered an "upgrade" option, though the best bet is to wipe it and start fresh.

Comment: yeahI figured it out. i was mostly just paranoid of messing up my boot, but all i had to do was make another media usb and do a custom install and put it over Windows 8 customer edition